# How to use preg_replace with url encoded $_GET?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a an url which looks like this `https://URL.DOMAIN/blog.php?id=43&q=echo%20%27test%27`.

When I use `<?php echo $_GET['q'] ?>` it displays `echo 'test'` which is what I want.

I am using this variable inside a `preg_replace` function which is basically made to apply a yellow background under matched strings:

```
preg_replace('/\b('.$_GET['q'].')\b/iu', '<span class="research-news-found">$1</span>', $news_content);
```

It works perfectly for "normal" strings like "apple" or whatever, but when there is a `'` inside the search query it doesn't match anything.

### Code example

```
$news_content = $news_display['news_description'];

if(isset($_GET['q'])){
   $news_content = preg_replace('/\b('.$_GET['q'].')\b/iu', '<span class="research-news-found">$1</span>', $news_content);
}
```

`$news_display['news_description']` contains the text output from DB.

Comment: @AbraCadaver the echo output works as before with this, but preg_replace still doesn't match what it should.

Comment: Need to show a full code example

Comment: Provide result of `var_dump($news_content, '/\b('.$_GET['q'].')\b/iu')`.

Comment: @user3783243 : var_dump just show  string(5369) " NEWS CONTENT ", in fact there is just no replacement. The preg_replace function doesn't match the content

Comment: The value of `'/\b('.$_GET['q'].')\b/iu'` is empty? The should at minimum be `/\b\b/iu`

Comment: Did you give up?

Comment: @AbraCadaver I ended up using a preg_replace_callback() with a preg_quote on the $_GET

Answer (score 0):

Just make the pattern greedy `?` and remove the trailing word boundary `\b` since `'` is not a word character and is a word boundary:

```
$news_content = preg_replace('/\b('.$_GET['q'].'?)/iu',
                             '<span class="research-news-found">$1</span>',
                             $news_content);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/80YCe)

But if you are hoping that it will actually `echo` *test*, then no.  You would need to restructure your question to state what you want to achieve, not how to get this replacement to work.